# Executing script inside method with BeanShell

Tags: java, scripting, beanshell

I'm not really sure how I can explain this, but here goes:

I want to be able to "insert" some commands into parts of my code which will be loaded from external files. To parse and execute these commands, I presumably have to use some scripting like BeanShell's eval method. The problem is that it doesn't seem to recognize the instance/method it's inside of. As a very basic example, I want to do something like

```
    public void somethingHappens()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Interpreter i = new Interpreter();
        i.eval("print(foo.getName());");
    }
```

Is this possible? Should I use other scripting tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using 1.6, you can use the built in JavaScript support.

The [Java Scripting Programmer's Guide](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html#jstojava) explains how to import Java classes into your script.

Code example 9 in this [article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/) explains how to pass objects into the script's scope.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the put method in the ScriptEngine class. I believe this will solve my issues so far.

Answer (score 0):

Using beanshell, this is something you can try

```
package beanshell;

import bsh.EvalError;
import bsh.Interpreter;

public class DemoExample {

    public static void main( String [] args ) throws EvalError  {
        Interpreter i = new bsh.Interpreter();
        String usrIp = "if(\"abc\".equals(\"abc\")){"
                + "demoExmp.printValue(\"Rohit\");"
                + "}";

        i.eval(""
                + "import beanshell.DemoExample;"
                + "DemoExample demoExmp = new beanshell.DemoExample();"
                + ""+usrIp);
    }

    public static void printValue(String strVal){
        System.out.println("Printing Value "+strVal);
    }
}
```